# Angular 4 Jasmine test spy on property to return different values to different tests

Tags: angular, properties, jasmine, spy

This is for Angular4 using Jasmine for testing.

I have a property that is getting called in a component from a getter in a service. In different cases (reflected in different tests), the service is either expected to return a string value or a null. I need to test a part of the code in the component that checks the value of that property for null, and navigates to a different place, depending on the property value. Here's the component code:

```
      this.authService.educatorPinToken
        ? this.router.navigate(['components/student/data-entry-summary'])
        : this.router.navigate(['components/student/student-dash']);
```

I have set up a mock service and added a spy on this property. I can set the property's value in the beforeEach, but I can't find a way to set a different value in each of my two tests. I tried this, but to no avail:

In the beforeEach:

```
  const authServiceMock = { get studentAgentId() { return null; }, deleteEducatorToken: null, get educatorPinToken() { return null; } };
  let educatorPinTokenSpy: jasmine.Spy;    

  beforeEach(() => {
    spyOnProperty(authServiceMock, 'studentAgentId').and.returnValue('1');
    educatorPinTokenSpy = spyOnProperty(authServiceMock, 'educatorPinToken').and.returnValue(null);
    spyOn(authServiceMock, 'deleteEducatorToken');
  });
```

And this code in the test itself:

```
educatorPinTokenSpy.and.returnValue('WXYZ');
fixture.detectChanges();
```

But it's not resetting the value - it's still returning null to the component. How can I do this?

Comment: I finally figured this out: In the beforeEach:

const authServiceMock = { get studentAgentId() { return null; }, deleteEducatorToken: null, get educatorPinToken() { return 'test'; } };
 
const authServiceMock = { get studentAgentId() { return null; }, deleteEducatorToken: null };
   beforeEach(() => {
     spyOnProperty(authServiceMock, 'studentAgentId').and.returnValue('1');
     spyOn(authServiceMock, 'deleteEducatorToken');
   });

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out: In the describe:

```
const authServiceMock = { get studentAgentId() { return null; }, deleteEducatorToken: null, get educatorPinToken() { return 'test'; } };

const authServiceMock = { get studentAgentId() { return null; }, deleteEducatorToken: null };
beforeEach(() => {
    spyOnProperty(authServiceMock, 'studentAgentId').and.returnValue('1');
    spyOn(authServiceMock, 'deleteEducatorToken');
```

});

I don't set up the spy in the beforeEach. I set it up in the "it" test as such:

```
const educatorPinTokenMock = TestBed.get(AuthService);
educatorPinTokenMock.educatorPinToken = 'WXYZ';
```

The trick is that I have to go back to the Test Bed to get this changed, as it's already set up by the time the test code executes.